# What units is transparency stored in ooxml?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

I have a pptx file with a single shape. Setting it to 70% transaprent I can compare the pptx and see the only difference is in /ppt/slides/slide1.xml

```
 <a:solidFill>
  <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
   <a:alpha val="40000"/>
  </a:schemeClr>
 </a:solidFill>
```

Anyone have any idea how on earth "70%" translates to "40000"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems different for me. My alpha values seem to use this function:

```
y = -1000x + 100000
```

Where `x` is the percentage and `y` is the alpha value. I recommend you do the same (figure out a function based on your computer and verify them) and not worry about it.

It seems each single percentage unit corresponds to 1000 of these alpha units.

Comment: So yo're saying `100 - (x-10000)/1000`? That gives the right value in this case, I guess I'll have to check about other cases.

Comment: I missed a 0. `y = -1000x + 100000` where `x` is the percentage and `y` is the alpha value. Or `i = 100 - (j / 1000)` where `j` is the alpha and `i` is the percerntage.