# DocumentFormat.OpenXml - how can I find an element's opacity

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml

I have a powerpoint document with a single slide containing a single rectangle with the default color at 70% opacity.

I open it using

```
var doc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.PresentationDocument
  .Open(@"path\to\pptx", false);
```

For the life of me, looking through the classes available from the doc root, I cannot find a property that specifies what the opacity of my shape is.

Where do I look to get opacity?

Comment: I'm really lazy to write the real answer, but open the Open XML Productivity Tool that comes with the OpenXML SDK. You will see a bunch of XML and their appropriate children. You can find the children on the MSDN site.

Comment: @jsn I can find it in the xml. I cannot find it in the doc object or its properties. I have even used powershell to load that object in and select-string a bunch of OuterXml propreties for 'alpha', or 'transparen', or 'opacit' none of these returned any hits. Here is a related question where I know what it is in the xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512198/what-units-is-transparency-stored-in-ooxml

Comment: What exact XML member are you trying to find (as in w:Text or whatever)?

Comment: @jsn - I am trying to find the transparency level on that shape. This is not directly in the Xml, but in the DocumentFormat.OpenXml library. I suppose if there is some way to find the a:solidFill element for that rectangle it might have the alpha value in it, but I have been unable to find that.

Comment: If it wasn't in the XML, the transparency won't show up. Hold on, I'm looking.

Comment: @jsn - it IS in the XML when I look on disk. The class that is returned by `PresentationDocument.Open()` though, while it is close to mirroring the file structure, is not exact. And it is in this class or any of its children that I cannot find information on transparency.

Comment: Too big to post as comment, see "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested, works.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DRAW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;

.....

using (PresentationDocument outputDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\YN\Desktop\80.pptx", true))
{

    Slide slide = outputDocument.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First<SlidePart>().Slide;
    CommonSlideData csd = slide.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
    ShapeTree st = csd.GetFirstChild<ShapeTree>();
    Shape s = st.GetFirstChild<Shape>();
    ShapeProperties sp = s.GetFirstChild<ShapeProperties>();
    DRAW.SolidFill sf = sp.GetFirstChild<DRAW.SolidFill>();
    DRAW.SchemeColor sc = sf.GetFirstChild<DRAW.SchemeColor>();
    DRAW.Alpha a = sc.GetFirstChild<DRAW.Alpha>();
    Console.WriteLine((int)a.Val);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, note that this is a very non-rigorous and non-automated way of getting it. You need to adjust this code to be more comprehensive obviously. Np.

Comment: Right, but at least I now know where to look.